# Reliable PHP script reentrant lock

Tags: php, locking, webserver

I have to make sure a certain PHP script (started by a web request) does not run more then once simultaneously.

With binaries, it is quite easy to check if a process of a certain binary is already around.

However, a PHP script may be run by several pathways, eg. CGI, FCGI, inside webserver modules etc. so I cannot use system commands to find it.

So how to reliable check if another instance of a certain script is currently running?

Comment: Set a flag of some sort: create a file, store a flag in a database, or use a Redis or memcached key. Just be sure you set it to expire eventually or clean it up manually if the first script dies.

Comment: It is hard to implement a reliable "expire" when the script may run for a long time. If it fails, we would need to wait for an unknown time to be sure it has died...

Comment: This could very well be an XY problem. For what particular reason do you require this check that PHP script is running only once? I'm asking because there's probably a way better approach to the real problem you're having that doesn't involve this perceived solution.

Comment: @dronus Very true, but you're going to have to handle that scenario somehow. One way to do it is update the flag (save a timestamp every so often). If the script is supposed to say every n seconds, "I'm still here," and doesn't check in for several minutes, you can pretty safely decide it's hung or dead.

Comment: Having the script to say "I am still there" would need some kind of cooperative multitasking, which may be hard to implement if the script does several different steps each one taking their time. Every call to an external program would then be forced to output on a regular interval to keep timeouts tight.

Answer (score 4):

The exact same strategy is used as one would chose with local applications:

The process manages a "lock file".

You define a static location in the file system. Upon script startup you check if a lock file exists in that location, if so you bail out. If not you first create that lock file, then proceed. During tear down of your script you delete that lock file again. Such lock file is a simple passive file, only its existence is of interest, often not its content. That is a standard procedure.

You can win extra candy points if you use the lock file not only as a passive semaphore, but if you store the process id of the generating process in it. That allows subsequent attempts to verify of that process actually still exists or has crashed in the mean time. That makes sense because such a crash would leave a stale lock file, thus create a dead lock.

---

To work around the issue discussed in the comments which correctly states that *in some of* the scenarios in which php scripts are used in a wen environment a process ID by itself may not be enough to reliably test if a given task has been successfully and completely processed one could use a slightly modified setup:

The incoming request does *not* directly trigger to task performing php script itself, but merely a wrapper script. That wrapper manages the lock file whilst delegating the actual task to be performed into a sub request to the http server. That allows the controlling wrapper script to use the additional information of the request state. *If* the actual task performing php script really crashes without prior notice, then the requesting wrapper knows about that: each request is terminated with a specific http status code which allows to decide if the task performing request has terminated normally or not. That setup should be reliable enough for most purposes. The chances of the trivial wrapper script crashing or being terminated falls into the area of a system failure which is something no locking strategy can reliably handle.

Comment: Great and accurate answer, I'd just love it if you could provide some code that illustrates your points :)

Comment: Storing a PID inside the file won't work, as there is no PID depending on the way PHP is run. If there where a PID, I would just check for the process running as I already mentioned.
Besides that, communicating at only two times (starting and finishing) is highly error prone, as PHP scripts may stop execution on several reasons (user abort, out of memory, webserver restart) and there is no reliable way to attach finalizing code.

Comment: So using a lock file would mean to refresh that lock file while the script is running, which is a peculiar procedure (like hand-crafted cooperative multitasking).

Comment: @dronus PHP allows to add code to the "tear down process" of request handling. Sure, if the script terminates prematurely in a hard way (why ever), then it might be that this is not executed. That is what I called a "crash" in my description which is why a cleanup strategy does make sense, as mentioned. If a process id can be used as described actually depends on _how_ you use php. Indeed in case of using php as a module inside the http server and if that module uses a prefork worker, then a given process might survive such a crash. That is true.

Comment: So this lock file scheme is very useful for classic binary applications (where it is used a lot) but not for the flaky world of PHP scripting I guess.

Of course the lock could be declared stale after "some time", but my processes may run for a long time and there is no good "some time". 

Maybe the PHP script should run another background process via `exec` and exit itself fast. But then all comunication to the client has to be done by complex AJAX polling using a bunch of additional requests.

Comment: @dronus As explained that strategy works perfectly fine for some of the scenarios asked. It does _not_ work without issues for _all_ scenarios, that is true. But that does not make the strategy worthless in itself and it does not create a "flaky world of PHP scripting".

Comment: @dronus You certainly can move the actual logic to be executed into a separate process to have a more reliable locking strategy. It is very well possible to do so while still being able to closely monitor things like progress and communication. Only you should not use the rather primitive `exec()` approach, but for a process and attach sockets to it which you can use to communicate with that process in any way you want at any time you want. Sure, that is more effort.

Comment: The strategy does not work. I was aware of lock files before, and already mentioned why this strategy fails in my environment. So the strategy may be the answer to many questions on SO but not to this one.

Comment: @dronus Would you care to elaborate why you claim that the strategy does not work for any of the scenarios you asked about in your question?

Comment: If PHP runs in a way that there is no unique PID for certain script (there are several ways), the lock file can't store a PID. It may store a timestamp of the script starting.
The script may stop now, without being able to execute the lock release code. That happens quite often on production systems using PHP.
Now how to decide if the script is still running? The only thing we could do is guessing by using the some "usual maximal run time". However that isn't something we would describe with "reliable".

Comment: If such a crash occurs "quite often on production systems" then I would consider this a severe issue with your architecture. That obviously means that your implementation is not robust enough for a production setup. But that was not the point: I already agreed that there are scenarios where the process ID by itself is _not_ a reliable means for the given purpose. You claimed it _never_ is, which is definitely wrong... Anyway, I extended the answer with a proposed setup to handle such a scenario. I never implemented that myself, so regard it as a suggestion, not more.

Comment: Using a http subrequest would need the guarantee that the sub-requested script would reliable stop all operations if the connection is dropped. PHP doesn't guranatee this either on certain setups!
So the wrapper script may finish and release the lock on for example user abort, but the sub requested script is still going on, now unlocked. 
Another request to the wrapper would reacquire the lock, but BANG, we have to sub-request scripts running.

Comment: A PHP script don't need to crash due to bad PHP code, it may be stopped due to webserver restart, out of memory or some other ressource etc. pp.

Comment: A production system handling hundreds of request per second usually don't care about one of a million requests aborted due to some circumstance.

Comment: On the other hand, using a shell script instead of a subrequest sounds feasable. A shell script has a PID, and reliable releases it on exit.

Comment: A subrequest will only return if either the execution has terminated or the executing script detaches from the request which would be something you'd have to implement in an explicit manner. I do not see a way where a request returns to the calling scope whilst the actual execution still continues without such explicit action.

Comment: A _hard_ http server restart in a production environment is a clear violation of operation principles. It certainly may cause issues, but that is immanent to such an action, nothing that can or should be handled from within. An out of memory exception is what I referred to with an implementation that is not robust enough for a production setup ("it does not scale").

Comment: PHP has a switch named `ignore_user_abort` to decide if it should stop execution if the request closes. And that switch doesn't work well depending on the environment.
An externally called binary (eg. by `passthru`) may not be killed if the user abort stops the PHP script, depending on the environment (if CGI, FCGI or modules are used and their configuration). This is a mess, but I have to cope with.

Comment: `ignore_user_abort` is exactly the intentional implementation I referred to. That is something you do by purpose. If you do that you will hardly be surprised if that happens. This is like saying a conditional around the removal of the lock file might result in the lock file not getting removed.

Comment: With the `passthru` command you refer to spawned processes that may _not_ be directly and fully controlled by the calling scope. Again: if you implement such strategies, then certainly you will not have full and complete control. But that does not say anything about the robustness of the locking strategy, more about you voluntarily crippling it. Sure you can do that. You can also voluntarily delete all scripts. That will also create issues. But you won't, or will you?

Answer (score 0):

As PHP does not always provide a reliable way of file locking (it depends on how the script is run, eg. CGI, FCGI, server modules and the configuration), some other environment for locking should be used.

The PHP script can for example call another PHP interpreter in it's CLI variant. That would provide a unique PID that could be checked for locking. The PID should be stored to some lock file then which can be checked for stale lock by querying if a process using the PID is still around.

Maybe it is also possible to do all tasks needing the lock inside a shell script. Shell scripts also provide a unique PID and release it reliable after exit. A shell script may also use a unique filename that can be used to check if it is still running.

Also semaphores (http://php.net/manual/de/book.sem.php) could be used, which are explicitely managed by the PHP interpreter to reflect a scripts lifetime. They seem to work quite well, however there is not much fuzz around about how reliable they are in case of premature script death.

Also keep in mind that external processes launched by a PHP script may continue executing even if the script ends. For example, a user abort on FCGI releases `passthru` processes, which carry on working despite the client connection is closed. They may be killed later if enough output accumulated or not at all.
So such external processes have to locked as well, which can't be done by the PHP-accquired semaphores alone.